# What is the proper way to complete cross-tab on the following segment in SQL?

Tags: sql, crosstab

I create frequencies on one column in SQL in a standard way.
My code is

```
select id , count(*) as counts   
from TABLE    
group by id   
order by counts desc
```

Suppose the output is as follows for six id

```
 id  counts
 --  -----
 1    3  two id have 3 counts per
 2    3 
 ---------
 3    6  three id have 6 counts per
 4    6
 5    6
 ---------
 6    2  one id has 2 counts
```

How can I produce the following?

```
nid  counts
---  ------
 1     2
 2     3
 3     6
```

I am writing in a hive environment, but that should be standard SQL. 
Thanks in advance for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You want two levels of aggregation:

```
select counts, count(*)
from (select id , count(*) as counts   
      from TABLE    
      group by id 
     ) c  
group by counts
order by counts;
```

I call this a "histogram-of-histograms" query.  I usually include `min(id)` and `max(id)` in the outer `select`, so I have examples of ids with given frequencies.